# How can I run JavaScript in Dart?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

Dart officially provides JavaScript language support through the [Dart web platform](https://dart.dev/web/js-interop) but for projects not using the web platform, there's unofficial support through a project called [`JSParser`](https://pub.dev/packages/jsparser).

Due to my unfamiliarity with the language combined with sparse documentation, I'm not sure how to use this `JSParser` library.  The example looks like this:

```
import 'package:parsejs/parsejs.dart';

void main() {
    new File('test.js').readAsString().then((String code) {
        Program ast = parsejs(code, filename: 'test.js')
        // Use the AST for something
    })
}
```

After [installing](https://pub.dev/packages/jsparser) the `ParseJS` library, the above code compiles just fine.  But how do I interact with "the AST"?  The IDE's code hinting doesn't seem to help either.

Looking back on the history of this project, it seems to have exchanged hands multiple times however all seem to be missing an example of what is done with the `ast` object afterward.

- 2014 - 2017: Managed by [asgerf/parsejs.dart](https://github.com/asgerf/parsejs.dart)
- 2019 - 2019: Managed by [anuragvohraec/parsejs.dart](https://github.com/anuragvohraec/parsejs.dart)
- 2020 - 2020: Forked by [ELEOS-MAP/parsejs.dart](https://github.com/ELEOS-MAP/parsejs.dart)
- 2019 - 2019: A fork from a fork by [anuragvohraec/dartJSEngine](https://github.com/anuragvohraec/dartJSEngine)

Steps I've done:

- Installed `flutter`
- Installed and [configured IntelliJ](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio) to use the flutter runtime I've installed
- Installed the beta [Desktop support](https://flutter.dev/desktop) for flutter
- Installed the library and try to run the example

Are these libraries too old or am I just using them wrong?  How would I know? I'm on Dart 2.11

Answer (score 2):

After combining a few examples, notably [this GitHub project](https://github.com/OrchidTechnologies/orchid/blob/e020c6eae066e44f98c8c013ffceede26d063183/gui-orchid/lib/api/configuration/js_config.dart#L1) and [this unit test](https://github.com/anuragvohraec/dartJSEngine/blob/master/testcases/testJSEngine.dart#L24), I can get the interpreter to work.

```
dependencies:
  dartjsengine: ^1.0.1
  jsparser: ^2.0.1
```

Note, this uses `JSEngine().visitProgram(...)` combined with the `parsejs()` function from JSParser.

```
import 'package:dartjsengine/dartjsengine.dart';
import 'package:jsparser/jsparser.dart';

main() {
  JsObject myObj = JSEngine().visitProgram(parsejs('var a = "red"; var b = "blue"; print(a); b;', filename: 'ignore'));
  print('${myObj?.valueOf}');
}
```

Outputs:

```
red
blue
```

Some major caveats:

- There's no alias from `print() -> console.log(...)`, so the example uses the undocumented `print(...)` (aliased from Dart I guess?)
- Several language features seem to be missing, importing an existing file as-is likely to fail.